# Did a pull from github to local eclipse and now all the new files from the server are considered conflits

Tags: eclipse, github

My coworker commited a bunch of files to our github repo.  I wanted to bring those files into my local workspace.  To this end, I went into team synchronizing and did a pull.  Now all the new files are red (conflict) and I can't commit anything because there are conflicts.  How could new files that I pulled from the repo be considered conflicts?  Please see the image that shows all the files.

[image]

Comment: Have you done any changes before pulling in those files?

Comment: I did a commit of some changes to another file, one file, then pulled in all the new ones.

Comment: When you open any of those files, can you see any place with conflicts? Like CONFLICT word and all this usual symbols for conflicts? Or eclipse just gives them "red flag"?

Comment: Hi, I opened one of these files in the comparison editor and it showed two files that were exactly the same with no conflicts (as one would expect, as I never modified these files)

Comment: Then I can only suggest you a workaround.. Save your edits for another file, you've mentioned, fetch all the code again from git repository in new directory and if everything works, apply your change and delete the previous directory.. I can't think of anything else..